# Can we have a 2 different textStyle inside styles.xml?

Tags: android, xml

I wanted my title to have italic and bold at the same time. How can I achieve this using styles.xml? or is it possible to achieve this within styles.xml only?

Comment: please (always) post your code, so your xml for your styles and your layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without `style.xml`

```
android:textStyle="bold|italic"
```

with `style.xml`

```
<style name="textViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.TextView">
       <item name="android:textStyle">bold|italic</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
android:textStyle="bold|italic"
```

check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textStyle)

Comment: `How can i achieve this on styles.xml?`

Comment: see my answer @a_local_nobody

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59999026/1712446 :)

Comment: @RonakPatel this isn't my question